# Confirmation on GridView SelectedIndexChanging or SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView on an ASP page that has one bound field showing. Following is the code for this gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnSelectedIndexChanging="confirmation" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ImportFileDescription" HeaderText="File Description" SortExpression="ImportFileDescription" ReadOnly="True" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Import" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When a record or row is selected, I need to have a confirmation box pop up, and then a sub will be executed on the server. Fumbling my way through this, I had thought that using the CommandField Select Button would work, but I am having issues. I am not sold on using the CommandField to accomplish this, I would be open to whatever method would be easiest. I could also have a checkbox or something next to each row and then only one "Import" button at the bottom that would import all that are selected. It really doesn't matter as long as I have: (1) the ability to choose which records will be imported and (2) the ability to create the confirmation box.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very broad right now. What are you really looking for? Some specific problem with CommandField? If so, describe the actual problem and post your confirmation box code. Some idea how to implement some particular requirements? if so, SO might not be the right place to ask this

Comment: I guess the latter would be more what I am looking for; I have no idea if the CommandField is a good way to accomplish my two requirements and I am just using it improperly, or if I need to find a different route.